# Word/phrase for free flight rides given to pilots

Tags: synonyms

I remember that pilots are given free flight rides on other flights and that there was a particular term/phrase for this. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Be careful with the phrase _free flight rides_. _Free rides_ or _free flights_ mean what you want, but _free flight_ means weightless flight, which can be achieved for short periods by conventional aircraft and is permanent in orbit. The weightless training flights do have a particular term/phrase among astronauts, however: the flights, and the planes, are called the Vomit Comet.

Comment: Jump seat flights or something more complicated?

Comment: This activity was called *deadheading*

Comment: Actually free flight means uncontrolled flight like what your hand glider does when you throw it in the air.

Comment: Is there a way to make my question explicitly clear without using hyphens? As in free flight-rides as compared to 'free-flight' rides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Wikipedia: [Deadheading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadheading_%28aeronautics%29).

> In aviation, deadheading is the practice of carrying members of an airline's flight staff free of charge when they are not working.

Comment: **Deadheading** is also used for a truck being driven empty, e.g., after making a delivery with no cargo for the return journey.